# T-cyclic subspace on Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$
>   over a field $F$. Let $\mathbf{0} \neq \mathbf{w_1} \in V$. Let $s$ be
>   the smallest positive integer such that $$T^s(\mathbf{w_1}) \in
>  \text{span}\{\mathbf{w_1},T(\mathbf{w_1}),...,T^{s-1}(\mathbf{w_1})\}$$
>
> First show the existence of such $s$. Then show that $B:=
>  \{\mathbf{w_1},T(\mathbf{w_1}),...,T^{s-1}(\mathbf{w_1})\}$ is a basis
>   of
>    $W:=\text{span}\{\mathbf{w_1},T(\mathbf{w_1}),T^2(\mathbf{w_1})......\}$

**Hi all, i would like my proof below to be verified if it is correct? Thanks!**

Suppose there does not exist $s$ such that $T^s(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(\mathbf{w_1},T(\mathbf{w_1}),...,T^{s-1}(\mathbf{w_1})\}$, then we see that starting from the very first case, $T(\mathbf{w_1}) \not \in \text{span}(\mathbf{w_1})$, $T^2(\mathbf{w_1}) \not \in \text{span}(\mathbf{w_1},T(\mathbf{w_1}))$. By expanding a linear independent set theorem, we have that $\mathbf{w_1},...,T^{s-1}(\mathbf{w_1}),T^s(\mathbf{w_1})$ are all linearly independent vectors in $V$.

Note that $V$ is of $\textbf{finite}$ dimensional. So let us say the dimension of $V$ is $\dim(V) = n$. By our assumption,$\mathbf{w_1},T(\mathbf{w_1}),T^2(\mathbf{w_1}),...,T^{n-1}(\mathbf{w_1})$ are linearly independent, however the vectors $\mathbf{w_1},T(\mathbf{w_1}),T^2(\mathbf{w_1}),...,T^n(\mathbf{w_1})$ are definitely linearly dependent as they consist of $n+1$ vectors. Hence, $T^n(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}\{\mathbf{w_1},T(\mathbf{w_1}),...,T^{n-1}(\mathbf{w_1})\}$. Hence it is a contradiction to our asusmption that there does not exist a $s$ such that $T^s(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(\mathbf{w_1},T(\mathbf{w_1}),...,T^{s-1}(\mathbf{w_1})\}$. We have shown such a $s$ exist and in particular $s \leq \dim V$. By the well ordering property, a smallest $s$ exists.

1. We show $\text{span}(B) = W$ by induction. Since $\text{span}(B) \subseteq W$ is given property, so it suffices to show that $W \subseteq \text{span}(B)$.

By induction, we want to show that $T^a(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(B)$ for all $a \geq 0$.

Base case of $a = 0$, indeed $\mathbf{w_1} \in \text{span}(B)$ by definition.

Suppose it is true for $a  = k$, that is we have it is true for $T^k(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(B)$. This means $T^k(\mathbf{w_1}) = a_0\mathbf{w_1}+a_1T(\mathbf{w_1})+...+a_{s-1}T^{s-1}(\mathbf{w_1})$

We proceed to show that $T^{k+1}(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(B)$.

Indeed:

$\begin{aligned}
T^{k+1}(\mathbf{w_1}) &= T(T^k(\mathbf{w_1}))\\ 
            &= T(a_0\mathbf{w_1}+a_1T(\mathbf{w_1})+...+a_{s-1}T^{s-1}(\mathbf{w_1}))\\
            &= a_0T(\mathbf{w_1})+a_1T^2(\mathbf{w_1})+...+a_{s-1}T^s(\mathbf{w_1})\\
\end{aligned}$

Note that $a_0T(\mathbf{w_1})+a_1T^2(\mathbf{w_1})+...+a_{s-2}T^{s-1}(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(B)$ by definition. And since hypothesis says that $T^s(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(B)$, we have by the closure property of subspaces that $a_0T(\mathbf{w_1})+a_1T^2(\mathbf{w_1})+...+a_{s-1}T^s(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(B)$

Hence we have proven the induction to be correct and that $T^a(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(B)$ for all $a \geq 0$. Hence $\text{span}(B) = W$.

2. We show that $B$ is linearly independent. Suppose a contradiction that $B$ is not linearly independent. That is $$a_0\mathbf{w_1}+a_1T(\mathbf{w_1})+...+a_{s-1}T^{s-1}(\mathbf{w_1}) = 0$$ has non trivial solution. There exists at least one $a_k$ where $k \in \{0,1,2,...,s-1\}$ such that $a_k \neq 0$.

Let $k \in \{0,1,2,...,s-1\}$ be the largest integer such that $a_k \neq 0$. Then we have $$a_0\mathbf{w_1}+a_1T(\mathbf{w_1})+...+a_kT^k(\mathbf{w_1}) = 0$$ where $a_k \neq 0$. We can rewrite the above as $$T^k(\mathbf{w_1}) = -\frac{1}{a_k}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_iT^i(\mathbf{w_1})$$ But this implies $T^k(\mathbf{w_1}) \in \text{span}(B)$. This contradicts the minimality of our hypothesis that $s$ is the smallest positive integer such that it can be in $\text{span}(B)$ since our $k < s$. Hence $B$ must be linearly indepedent.

Hence $B$ is a basis of $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point looks good. For the second point, you don't need to use induction, you can do it directly by contradiction.

Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you sir, how about the proof on showing $B$ is linearly independent, did i use the contradiction right?

Comment: @ilovewt Yes, you did.

Comment: Thank you! One last little request, i have edited the existence part to be more precise, do you think there is any logic flaws in the argument?